# Set option of select form with JavaFX webengine.executeScript()

Tags: javascript, javafx

I'm building a webcrawler with UI using JavaFX. I'm trying to preselect birthday day, month and year. So there is three select blocks. Unfortunately, there is no id, just a name 'birthday.day', 'birthday.month' and 'birthday.year' respectively.
I can fill other elements of the form like username and password, but no luck on a select so far. Here is what i tried:

```
engine.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[0].selected='selected'");
engine.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('birthday.month')[0].selectedIndex=2");      
engine.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('birthday.year')[0].selectedIndex=2");`
```